# Windows store app developers?? Is it so hard to develop applications for windows store?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

I have seen many applications related to many domains in all other Operating systems but in the windows store there are very less applications available and that creates a lot of negative impact on the customers phone choice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most of app developers think: "The most popular mobile platforms are iOS and Android. So, we will develop our app only for those platforms because there are too few Windows Phone users and we need to save our money

Many young programmers think: "There is too few work for Windows Phone developers. I would better choose another field of work"

Comment: I agree the users are less when compared to Android and iOS but indeed there is a rise in the use of windows phone. But dont you think that it affects the market also negatively?. People prefer having smartphones because of the social networking..!! When there are very few social networking applications then people would automatically choose not to go for windows  phone. Isn't it the case?

Comment: @BhagyaHosur yes, it affects market negatively. Users don't want to buy smartphones without apps, and developers don't want to create apps for a nonpopular platform. Vicious circle. Yes, there is a rise of Windows Phone sells but is still not enough

Answer (score 1):

If you know XAML and C#, it's easy and fun to create Windows Store and Windows Phone Applications.

If you don't know any of these two, don't worry you can create these applications in HTML, CSS, JS also.

Or you can choose XAMARIN or APACHE CORDOVA to create applications.

You have also another choice - Unity.